# dropdown list doesn't work with knockout.js+Browserify when adding a 'require' to 'knockout'

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, browserify

I am new with Knockout.js and Browserify.
I am trying to implement an example from the Knowckout website: http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/29939/
(it works fine on jsfiddle).

However, in order to use knockout with Browserify i created the the bundle by running `browserify -r knockout > bundle_target.js` and added `var ko = require('knockout');` on the top of the javascript file: http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/29941/ (otherwise 'ko' doesn't defined in the javascript).

After doing that, the dropdown list stop working (probably something related to $root).

[EDIT]:
I notice that even when removing the require and and include the knockout.js directly (without broserify), the page is blank unless I remove the **$root**.

Am I doing something wrong here (probably yes).

Thanks, 
Mike

Comment: You need to either load require or not have var ko = require

Answer (score 0):

I though that I did some trivial mistake but I found that the problem was related to section in the html code. Adding backslash before the dollar sign `\$root` solved the problem.